# Find matching words from a list in a string, return the matching word(s) - Py

Tags: python, string, matching

I am writing a code to check if the words of a string match with a list of words. I already have the following function that works perfectly:

```
def lookup(string,list_of_words):
     if any(i in string for i in list_of_words)==True:
        return 1
     else:
        return 0
```

However, now I want the function not to return 0's or 1's, but the word that matches, ej:

```
list_of_words=['pencil','eraser','marker']
lookup2('I have a pencil and a pen', list_of_words)
#output: 
'pencil'
```

I wrote the following code but it returns the error `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`:

```
def lookup2(string,list_of_words):
    if any(i in string for i in words)==True:
        return i
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Do you guys know how can I make it work properly?
Thank you

Comment: The `==True` is not needed; and technically incorrect.  Additionally, as far as I can tell, `numpy` should not be tagged. This is pure list manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another variation:

```py
>>> list_of_words = ['pencil', 'eraser', 'marker']
>>> sentence = 'I have a pencil and a pen'
>>> [word for word in list_of_words if word in sentence]
['pencil']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that worked

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def lookup2(string,list_of_words):
    return ','.join(j for j in string.split() if j in list_of_words)
```

Essentially, what it is doing is:

1. Iterating over splitted string's elements (`.split()` method returns a list)
2. Checking if any word is in `list_of_word`
3. Joining it by `,`

Answer (score 1):

```
def lookup2(string, list_of_words):
    return set(string.split()).intersection(list_of_words)

list_of_words = ['pencil', 'eraser', 'marker']
print(lookup2('pencil eraser', list_of_words))  # {'pencil', 'eraser'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can be made to work by using the [Walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) available in Python 3.8+.

```
def lookup2(string, list_of_words):
    if any((p:=i) in string for i in list_of_words):  # ==True not needed
        return p                                      # p value maintained from list comprehension
    else:
        return None                                   # None more standard to return for string matching
```

Or more succinctly:

```
def lookup2(string, list_of_words):
    return p if any((p:=i) in string for i in list_of_words) else None
```